# Converting native Android app to gradle-experimental 0.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to convert [any project tango sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c) to use the new experimental gradle build system.  I downloaded an app, verified that it builds and deploys, and then updated files following the [experimental-gradle guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental).  The process was straight-forward, except for the app build.gradle file, shown below before and after my edits.  I have been studying the [gradle plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), the experimental guide, etc, but haven't figured out what to do with sourceSets and the two tasks and keep getting errors.  What is the right way to modify build.gradle?

Note:
I used point-cloud-jni-example, but these changes should be the same for any project tango app, because the relevant files are essentially identical for all the tango sample apps.

**stock app build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.projecttango.experiments.nativepointcloud"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [];
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}

task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def ndkbuild = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir', null)+"/ndk-build"
    commandLine ndkbuild, '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

**modified app build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 19
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.projecttango.experiments.nativepointcloud"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
        }

        android.sourceSets.main {
            jniLibs.srcDir = 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = [];
        }
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
            ndk.with {
                debuggable = true
            }
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "point_cloud_jni_example"
        ldLibs += ["android", "EGL", "GLESv2", "dl", "log"]
        stl     = "stlport_static"
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}

task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def ndkbuild = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir', null)+"/ndk-build.cmd"
    commandLine ndkbuild, '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: @proppy could you look at this?

Comment: can you try to remove `android.sources` and `task.ndkBuild`? No need to call nkd-build anymore, gradle is now capable of building cpp files directly without generating Android.mk files.

Comment: I removed them, but tasks.withType(JavaCompile) depends on ndkBuild.  Syncing gradle then gives me  
Error:Could not find property 'ndkBuild' on task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.

Comment: you should also remove that dependency

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it resolves all issues.

In any case, you have to change your `buildTypes` block using:

```
android.buildTypes {
    release {
         minifyEnabled = false
         proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
    }
}
```

Also use the last version 0.2.1

Comment: Thank you.  I updated the code and also added ndk.with{debuggable=true}.  Thanks to you, I'm getting past that error.  Now, I think I'm having problems with dependencies - there are errors relating to missing tango files (see updated question).

Comment: @Nate I don't know if with the current plugin you can specify includes directly. May be you can use the cppFlags. Take a look here:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/Teapot/app/build.gradle

Comment: Gradle now syncs without errors (I had srcDirs 'src/main/jni' instead of srcDirs 'src/main/libs' in my code).  Anyway, now it crashes on startup with:  

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load point_cloud_jni_example from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/libtango_device.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.projecttango.experiments.nativepointcloud-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.projecttango.experiments.nativepointcloud-2, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null